# WatiN: How to Run the exe file instead of Saving it from the FileDownloadHandler

Tags: c#-4.0, watin

I am new in using WatiN and couple it with C# for my automation needs. I am faced with a situation here. I need to run an executable from a server location. After having clicked on the download link in the IE, I have a file download pop-up in front of me and a "File Download - Security Warning" on top. The UI presents me with 3 options of Run, Save and Cancel.

I want to click the Run button to run the exe directly (and not hit Save to download it to some location). I have added the dialog handler for my filedownloadhandler to my IE instance. Please find the screen-shot attached

Is there a way in WatiN to accomplish this? Any sample code is highly appreciated.

Thanks.!
[Capture Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNt1E.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Use your existing dialog handler add and remove but the type of handler you would add would be

WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileDownloadHandler dialogHandler1 = new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileDownloadHandler(WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileDownloadOptionEnum.Run);

Note that this won't work with IE 9. I have an open post on this (Download Handler for IE9).
Hope this helps.

Cheers.